# How to decide runtime fetching type(Eager/Lazy) of nested object List by jpa annotation,

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I ve implemented this things by hibernate annotation (@FetchProfile) but now I want to do it by JPA.
is there any way to do it??

Comment: When you did with Hibernate, you did with JPA only. Whats your actual question ?

Comment: Use `@Fetch` (*"`@FetchProfile` do the same thing as `@Fetch` do"*, http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/fetchprofile_hibernate_annotation).

Comment: @FetchProfile is hibernate specific(as per my knowledge),in future if there be need to change framework,I have to change it as well ,so I am looking for JPA anotation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `JPA 2.1 Entity Graph` you can control fetching at run-time, check [this blog](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/2014/03/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-1-named-entity.html) or [this blog](http://hantsy.blogspot.com/2013/12/jpa-21-entity-graph.html) for more details.

Comment: Also good resource: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-entitygraphs002.htm